# Need further help and verification regarding a dynamic model problem

Tags: dynamical-systems

We have the model $y= ax(1-x)$ and we want to find the period 2 solutions such that $X_{n} = X_{n+2} $ and $X_n \neq X_{n+1}$. My teacher told us to do this problem with the quadratic formula. This is my attempt:

$y = ax (1-x)$, so for period 2 we'd want $x = a(ax(1-x))(1-ax(1-x))$. Factor out the parentheses and you get $$x = -a^3x^4 + 2a^3x^3-a^3x^2 -a^2x^2 + a^2x$$

Here I am confused because I am supposed to use a quadratic formula for a quartic function.

Comment: "so for period 2 we'd want $x=ax(1−ax(1−x))$" No, you'd want $x = a(ax(1-x))(1-ax(1-x))$. Since you know two solutions to that (the solutions of $x = ax(1-x)$), polynomial division gives you a quadratic polynomial whose zeros you need to find.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ohhh darn forgot about the other x, stupid of me. I'll have to edit this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two fixed points, $z_0 = 0$ and $z_1 = (a-1)/a$ are also solutions of $X_{n+2} = X_n$, hence you can divide those two out of the equation

$$a^3x^4 - 2a^3x^3 +a^2(a+1)x^2 - (a^2-1)x = 0$$

(you have miscalculated the coefficient of $x^2$), to obtain the quadratic equation

$$a^2x^2 - a(a+1)x + (a+1) = 0$$

for the two points of the 2-cycle.

First, for the fixed points, we have the equation $x = ax(1-x)$, which, expanded and rearranged becomes

$$ ax^2 - (a-1)x = 0$$

and we can read off the two solutions $z_0 = 0$ and $z_1 = (a-1)/a$ immediately.

Then, for the points with $X_{n+2} = X_n$, we have the equation $x = f(f(x))$, which, substituting $f(w) = aw(1-w)$ expands to

$$x = af(x)\bigl(1-f(x)\bigr) = a^2x(1-x)\bigl(1-ax(1-x)\bigr) = a^2x\bigl(1-x -ax(1-x) + ax^2(1-x)\bigr)$$

and then

$$x = a^2x(1 -(a+1)x +2ax^2 - ax^3) = x(-a^3x^3 + 2a^3x^2 - (a+1)a^2x + a^2).$$

Rearranging yields

$$x\bigl(a^3x^3 - 2a^3x^2 + (a+1)a^2x - (a^2-1)\bigr) = 0.$$

We already know that $z_0$ and $z_1$ are solutions (I have already factored out $x - z_0$), and thus we can write the polynomial expression on the left hand side as $(x - z_0)(x - z_1)Q(x)$ with a quadratic polynomial $Q$. Now we split off the factor $x - z_1$, or, better $a\cdot(x - z_1) = ax - (a-1)$ from the cubic factor.

$$\bigl(a^3x^3 - 2a^3x^2 + (a+1)a^2x - (a^2-1)\bigr) = \bigl(ax - (a-1)\bigr)\cdot Q(x)$$

To determine $Q$, we start with the highest-order term, and it's clear that must be $a^2x^2$ to obtain the highest-order term $a^3x^3$ of the cubic polynomial. $\bigl(ax - (a-1)\bigr)\cdot a^2x^2 = a^3x^3 - a^2(a-1)x^2$, so

$$\bigl(a^3x^3 - 2a^3x^2 + (a+1)a^2x - (a^2-1)\bigr) = \bigl(ax-(a-1)\bigr)\cdot a^2x^2 + R(x)$$

with $R(x) = -a^2(a+1)x^2 + a^2(a+1)x - (a^2-1)$. Splitting off $ax - (a-1)$ from $R(x)$ yields the next term of $Q(x)$, namely $-a(a+1)x$.

$$\bigl(ax - (a-1)\bigr)\cdot a(a+1)x = a^2(a+1)x^2 -a(a+1)(a-1)x$$

then gives us

$$\bigl(a^3x^3 - 2a^3x^2 + (a+1)a^2x - (a^2-1)\bigr) = \bigl(ax - (a-1)\bigr)\cdot\bigl(a^2x^2 - a(a+1)x\bigr) + S(x)$$

with $S(x) = a(a+1)x - (a^2-1) = (a+1)\bigl(ax - (a-1)\bigr)$, so wrapping up, we obtain the factorisation

$$x\bigl(ax - (a-1)\bigr)\cdot\bigl(a^2x^2 - a(a+1)x + (a+1)\bigr) = 0$$

and the two zeros of the last factor are the points with $X_{n+2} = X_n \neq X_{n+1}$.

Comment: I don't really understand how you divided them out. Could you further explain what you did?

Comment: Yes, will do, but now I'm off for dinner, will elaborate after that, sorry for the delay.

Comment: No problem, enjoy your dinner.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the effort. I have to admit, this is a whole lot for me to digest. For a starter, how can you *immediately* see that $z_0 = 0$ and $z_1 = \dfrac{a-1}{a}$. I can see the $z_0$ fairly quickly, but I most certainly don't see $z_1$ quickly

Comment: Splitting into factors, the equation for the fixed points is $x\cdot\bigl(ax - (a-1)\bigr) = 0$. The second factor is $0$ iff $ax = a-1 \iff x = (a-1)/a$. I guess one starts to see such things immediately after one has enough practice.